# Angular 13 add Validator on blur

Tags: angular, validation

is it possible to add a Validator after the form initialisation and to set it to trigger only on blur ?

For example, I can add a new Validator using addValiators :

```
this.form.controls['pseudo'].addValidators(SignupValidators.someCustomValidator);
```

Is it possible to set the 'someCustomValidator' to trigger only on blur. What I am actually trying to do is to have only one of the field validators to trigger on blur. I am currently using this code inside my html file:

```
(blur)="checkPseudoAvailability($event)"
```

I am looking for a clean solution, not for improvisations

Comment: you can tigger control value update on blur. validation will happend also only on blur. Also in case you want your control to become red only after interaction with it, you would better check if it is `.touched` as angular material does by default

Comment: Thank you for your comment @Andrei, but I don't understand what you are proposing as a solution.